# Calculate % starch breakdown of apples

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm a scientific researcher that work in the pome industry. If you know we do maturity parameters on apples in some of our trails. One of the maturity parameters is to determine starch breakdown of apples by cutting the apple in half and treating it with iodine. Starch when reacting to iodine turns black (as in picture).Therefor the white parts is starch already converted to sugar. Then a % of starch breakdown to sugar is determined by means of looking at a breakdown starch breakdown chart (so basically a estimated guess). I'm therefor trying to do this by using python to calculate the number of black pixels and white pixels and then express it as a percentage. How would one go about this ? Firstly to identify the boundaries of an apple and then to basically calculated the number of black and white pixels. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Starch breakdown, transparent background:

[image: Starch breakdown, transparent background]

Starch breakdown of honey crisp apples:

[image: Starch breakdown of honey crisp apples]

This is how far I have come (notice if only been coding for a week)
Code to identify outlines of apples:

```
    import cv2

    # Read the original image
    img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\marnes\\Downloads\\starch-staining- 
    patterns-in-Honeycrisp-applesx.png')

    # Convert to graycsale
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Blur the image for better edge detection
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3, 3), 0)

    #display
    cv2.imshow('Original', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imshow('img_gray', img_gray)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imshow('img_blur', img_blur)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Canny Edge Detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)  # 
    Canny Edge Detection

    # Display Canny Edge Detection Image
    cv2.imshow('Canny Edge Detection', edges)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and then I have tried to split the black and white pixels.

```
    import cv2
    #read image
    image = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\marnes\\Downloads\\starch-staining- 
    patterns-in-Honeycrisp-applesx.png')
    #convert image to grayscale
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # apply binary thresholding
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    # visualize the binary image
    cv2.imshow('Binary image', thresh)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imwrite('image_thres1.jpg', thresh)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    # detect the contours on the binary image using 
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, 
    mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    # draw contours on the original image
    image_copy = image.copy()
    cv2.drawContours(image=image_copy, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, 
    color=(0, 50 , 0), thickness=2,
             lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    # see the results
   cv2.imshow('None approximation', image_copy)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.imwrite('contours_none_image1.jpg', image_copy)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Some questions: (1) Would it be possible to take the pictures on a plain white background so we have a good outer contour? (2) Which programming language do you use? (3) Do you have some code already, that explains where you got stuck?

Comment: To answer your questions above; (1)  It's not possible to take photos from a white background at the moment since we don't have any apple trails currently (out of season), but I did add a photo with the background removed. (2) I'm using python (3) I have only been coding for a week (attached code above) , so I don't know where to start or how to pull everything together, So i just need a little help where to start and from there I'm willing to go do further research on the topic. If been working with opencv.  Thanks for the reply

Comment: How are these images taken? Do you control the illumination and the camera aperture, integration time and whitebalance settings? All of these things are important for color and brightness consistency. Also, how consistent is the color and darkness of the iodine? If things are consistent, this is an easy problem. If things are not consistent, this is a **really** hard problem.

Comment: To this point in time no images are taken. Starch breakdown is done manually by comparing the starch breakdown of each apple to a given apple starch breakdown chart. But because of different starch breakdown patterns as well as human error this could sometimes lead to data that are unreliable. I therefor though that this could be done by taking pictures in some way and then determining the starch breakdown down to the pixel (since the two color present are white and black). But I clearly underestimated the complexity of this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Is something like this possible ? I think there is a lot of potential for it here in South Africa from a research perspective.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is possible. What I’m saying is that you should start by setting up the imaging system. The better you do that, the simpler the programming part will be.

Comment: Can one use OpenCV to connect your phone camera or would it be better to take photos by professional camera ? (because this might be time consuming during a busy season of working hundreds of samples per day)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can try to continue:

1. get largest contour and measure size in pixel (100%)
2. get dark areas by threshold and measure size in pixel
3. calculate %

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('img7.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# get shape of largest contour and count pixels
edges = cv2.Canny(image=img, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
max_contour = max(contours, key=lambda c: cv2.contourArea(c))
mask = np.zeros_like(gray)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [max_contour], 0, 255, -1)
pct_100 = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

# get dark area and count pixels
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, mask)
pct_dark = cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
cv2.imshow("dark", thresh)

print(f"mask = {pct_100}, dark = {pct_dark}, %dark = {pct_dark / pct_100 * 100}")

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Example output for image #7:

[image]

```
mask = 42956, dark = 7120, %dark = 16.575100102430394
```